# Laravel Eloquent query recursive relationship model with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, recursion, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building a store, where I have to display to the user all products in a given category and all other products that are contained in the subsequent subcategories of the currently accessed one. The categories have the N+1 problem since there can be infinite subcategories. I want to be able to filter trough these products and also to be able to paginate them.
This is my categories model:

```
   class CatalogCategory extends Model
   {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App/CatalogCategory','parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany($this,'parent_id')
            ->orderBy('order_place','ASC')
            ->with('children');
    }

    /*
    *   Return products, that belong just to the parent category.
    */

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CatalogProduct','parent_id')
            ->where('is_active', 1)
            ->whereDate('active_from', '<=', Carbon::now('Europe/Sofia'))
            ->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    }

    /*
    *   Return all products contained in the parent category and its children categories.
    */

    public function all_products()
    {
        $products = $this->products;

        foreach ($this->children as $child) {
            $products = $products->merge($child->all_products());
        }

        return $products;
    }

}
```

The all_products() method returns all of the products, that I want, but since it's a collection i'm unable to paginate or filter through it. My question is if there is a better way to retrieve the products and how to retrieve them so, that i can query them for filtering and paginate them?

Comment: cant you run this query in the controller????

Comment: This is my question, how can i query the recursive relationship to get all products in the category and the subsequent subcategories, but to be able to paginate and filter trough them

Comment: Look at https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list that package creates CTE queries which allow recursive lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested set technique to store categories.

Nested set technique allows to retrieve all descendants or ancestors for a certain node in hierarchical structures in one query.

You could try this package: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset. Imho it's the best implentation of nested set in laravel.

Installation and configuring will cost you 10 min.

After that you could retrieve your products something like this:

```
public function products($slug) 
{
    //first query: retrieving current category
    $category = CatalogCategory
        ::where('slug', $slug)
        ->first();
    
    //second query: retrieving all category descendants and self ids.
    $categoryIds = $category
        ->descendants
        ->pluck('id')
        ->push($category->id);

    //third query: retrieving all products.
    $products = CatalogProduct
        ::whereIn('parent_id', $categoryIds)
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->whereDate('active_from', '<=', Carbon::now('Europe/Sofia'))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        ->paginate(50);

    return view('path_to_view', compact('products', 'category'));
}
```